# Why is $f(x)=\int_{1}^{x^2} \frac{\ln(xt)}{1+t}dt$ continuously differentiable and what is it's derivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

In doing some old exam questions, I came across the following problem. Let $f:(1,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$f(x)=\int_{1}^{x^2} \frac{\ln(xt)}{1+t}dt$$
Questions:

a) Reason as to why f is continuously differentiable and find an integral-free representation of the derivative

b) Show that $f'(x)>0$ for $x>1$

I assume (b) will be trivial when (a) is solved.

For (a) my approach was integrating more or less directly, then differentiating. I end up caught in a cycle of integrating by parts: 
$$\int_{1}^{x^2} \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}dt$$and
$$\int_{1}^{x^2} \frac{\ln(t)}{t+1}dt$$
keep coming back... I don't have anything in my toolbox (that I know of) that lets me crack this.

So I assume that either I shouldn't actually integrate and then differentiate or I'm missing something in my "integration-toolbelt". What's going on here? Also, I don't actually know how to "Reason as to why f is continuously differentiable", are my problems connected?

Comment: Please check the conditions for the Leibniz integral rule

Comment: A similar question that might inspire you : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/838304

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the fact that $\ln(xt)=\ln x+\ln t$. So $f(x)=\ln  \, x\int_1^{x^{2}} \frac 1 {1+t} dt+\int_1^{x^{2}} \frac {\ln  t } {1+t}dt$ and the first term is $(\ln x) (\ln (1+x^{2})-\ln 2)$. You can now write down $f'$ easily.

It is also quite easy to show that $f'(x) >0$ for $x >1$. I will leave that to you.

Comment: How do I find the derivative of the second integral without integrating?

Comment: @RubenKruepper: Look up “Fundamental theorem of calculus”

Comment: @MartinR Doesn't the fact that our upper bound grows quadratically, not linearly, matter?

Comment: @RubenKruepper: Sure (which means that you need the *chain rule* as well).

Comment: @MartinR I honestly thought of that two seconds after posting, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$ let\; y(x)\;=\;\int_{1}^{x^2} \frac{\ln(xt)}{t+1}dt$$
Therefore y(x) = $ \int_{1}^{x^2} \frac{\ln(x)}{t+1}dt\; $ + $ \int_{1}^{x^2} \frac{\ln(t)}{t+1}dt $
$$ $$Hence y(x) = $\int_{1}^{x^2} \frac{\ln(t)}{t+1}dt\; $ + $ ln(x)\, \int_{1}^{x^2} \frac{1}{t+1}dt $
$$ $$
Now differentiate $$ \frac{dy}{dx}\;= \frac{2xlnx^2}{1+x^2}\; + \; lnx\,\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\;+\; (\frac{1}{x})(\; \int_{1}^{x^2}\frac{1}{1+t})dt $$
$$ $$
since all terms are positive for x $\gt1\;$hence f'(x)$\gt0$